# Returning Index of Array with Maximum Element Value

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing

I have the following np.array

```
arry=[0, 0, np.array([858.56]), 0, 0, 0, 0, np.array([59.778]), np.array([817.752])]
```

I am using the following code to find the index where the array element is maximum:

```
maximum=np.where(arry == np.amax(arry))
```

However, I am getting wrong index. What could be the problem?

Comment: This is a list which contains numpy arrays and ints. What index are you expecting to get? I get 2, which is indeed the index of the maximum value (858.56)

Comment: @JoeTodd I got an issue because one of the array was double bracketed np.array([[858.56]])